# Few were cited more often than?

Tags: meaning-in-context, relative-pronouns

What does this mean, "few...more often than"?

---

> YEARS LATER, PHYSICISTS would give wistful looks when they talked
>   about Lorenz's paper on those equations- that beautiful marvel of a
>   paper. "By then it was talked about as if it were an ancient scroll,
>   preserving secrets of eternity. In the thousands of articles that made
>   up the technical literature of chaos **few were cited more often
>   than** "Deterministic Nonperiodic Flow." For years, no single object
>   would inspire more illustrations,even motion pictures, than the
>   mysterious curve depicted at the end, the double spiral that became
>   known as the Lorenz attractor. For the first time, Lorenz's pictures
>   had shown what it meant to say, "This is complicated." All the
>   richness of chaos was there.

Comment: Try changing "few" to "five" or "47" or "five articles" or "47 articles".  Does the phrase make sense with this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, "[few](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/few)" means "only a small number [of articles]".

Comment: After reading this sentence once again, I think I catch the meaning. Thanks.